# A special World trip

Tags: knowledge, geography

My wife and I went on a World trip. We started visiting countries in this order:

[image]

[image]

[image]

For a while we were stuck, but in December 2022 we could finally continue our trip and visited these countries:

[image]

[image]

Which country did we visit next?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The next country visited was:

> **BRAZIL**
>
>  [image: Flag of Brazil]

This will also (for now, anyway) be the last stop on your world tour. Why? Because:

> The flags shown (in order) are those of **Australia**, **England**, **France**, **Argentina**, and **Italy**.
>
>  This is a sequence based on the **number of [men's FIFA World Cup wins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup)**:
>
>  Australia - 0 wins
>  England - 1 win
>  France - 2 wins
>  Argentina - 3 wins
>  Italy - 4 wins
>
>  So continuing the sequence, the next stop on your tour will be the only country that has won 5 World Cups: **Brazil**!

Note that this also explains the remark about being able to continue your tour last December...

> As until Argentina won the Qatar tournament at the end of 2022, there was no country who had won the World Cup exactly 3 times!

Comment: You are absolutely right and nicely explained!

Comment: I went on a wild goose chase of taking their FIFA rankings, A1Z26ing them, and using the cute Merriam-Webster Unabridged Cryptogram feature to get “Aruban”. Good job! +1

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I was already partway through my write-up when you modified the question to add the December remark, so it wasn't essential for the solve but it does add a nice extra element to the story and explanation :)

Comment: Yeah I figured the December remark makes a better story and also helps in solving it.